# What is the purpose to define central moment?

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the purpose to define central moment?
I searched the google and all i could find is bunch of properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I got your question, one of the 'purposes' of central moment is to set $n=2$ and get the variance of the rv, which is a measure of dispersion around the mean. Higher central moments (e.g. kurtosis) can also be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often, you're interested in the characteristics of a distribution *independent* from where exactly its located on the $x$-Axis, or in other words independent from its *mean*.

The central moments do exactly that - they are the moments after shifting the random variable such that its mean becomes zero. I.e. the central $k$-th moment of $X$ is the $k$-th moment of $X-\mathbb{E}X$.